# Using Objective-C project in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I would like to be able to use this project in my own:
https://github.com/matibot/MBCircularProgressBar

But the problem is that the language used in there is objective-c and I only know swift. Is there a way to make it work in my project?

Comment: You should search on google about "bridging header swift objective-c". You will find something like this: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Answer (score 0):

You can bridge Objective-C to Swift with a bridging header. Rather than explaining in a post, this document explains the whole process. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html